# Is there a last.fm app for iOS to submit the music I'm listening to ?

Tags: ios, music, last.fm

Is there a last.fm app for iOS to submit the music I'm listening to ?

Now with iCloud I'm not connecting my devices anymore by cable to the mac, so the tracks are never submitted.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found CloudScrop in the app store. When you start it it automatically looks for any music played since the last run and submits the tracks to LastFM.

Answer (score 1):

[iScrob](http://iscrob.com/) seems to do what you want *on the iPhone*. I found after a very brief search, used it for an hour or so after answering this question and found it to be pretty neat.

With iOS 5 I can see the track I'm playing in the lock screen and control `iScrob` as I would `Music`.

[image: Controls]

It also displays album artwork on the lock screen:

[image]

The only disadvantage is that I can't create Genius playlists.

Comment: Briefly, with iScrob I need to use their app to submit tracks to last.fm. Correct ? I want to use the Apple Music app instead, and possibly having something working in background.

Comment: Ya but using an iPhone app, on iPad rather than using Music is not the best...

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have an iPad (and it wasn't mentioned in the question), so I don't know what would work well there.

Comment: In the question i mentioned iOS